# Не работает функция отправки отзыва

Tags: php, mysql

Данные в базу не отправляются,поля не подсвечиваются.С бд все нормально,если добавить отзыв напрямую через нее,то все выводится

$('#button-send-review').click(function(){

```
   var name = $("#name_review").val();
   var good = $("#good_review").val();
   var bad = $("#bad_review").val();
   var comment = $("#comment_review").val();
   var iid = $("#button-send-review").attr("iid");

    if (name != "")
     {
          name_review = '1';
          $("#name_review").css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
      }else {
           name_review = '0';
           $("#name_review").css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
      }

    if (good != "")
       {
          good_review = '1';
          $("#good_review").css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
      }else {
          good_review = '0';
          $("#good_review").css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
      }

    if (bad != "")
     {
          bad_review = '1';
          $("#bad_review").css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
     }else {
          bad_review = '0';
          $("#bad_review").css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
     } 


            // Глобальная проверка и отправка отзыва

    if ( name_review == '1' && good_review == '1' && bad_review == '1')
      {
         $("#button-send-review").hide();
         $("#reload-img").show();

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/include/add_review.php",
         data: "id="+iid+"&name="+name+"&good="+good+"&bad="+bad+"&comment="+comment,
         dataType: "html",
         cache: false,
         success: function() {
         setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
         }
         });  
         }         
});
```

add_review.php:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{  
 include("db_connect.php");
 include("../functions.php");

 $id = clear_string($_POST['id']);
 $name = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['name']));
 $good = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['good']));
 $bad =  iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['bad']));
 $comment =  iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['comment']));

            mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO table_reviews(product_id,name,good_reviews,bad_reviews,comment,date)
                        VALUES(                     
                            '".$id."',
                            '".$name."',
                            '".$good."',
                            '".$bad."',
                            '".$comment."',
                             NOW()                          
                        )");    

echo 'yes';
}
?>
```

response:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'whatshelp';
    src:url('../fonts/whatshelp/whatshelp.eot?nusorz');
    src:url('../fonts/whatshelp/whatshelp.eot?nusorz#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/whatshelp/whatshelp.ttf?nusorz') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/whatshelp/whatshelp.woff?nusorz') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/whatshelp/whatshelp.svg?nusorz#whatshelp') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="wh-icon-"], [class*=" wh-icon-"] {
    /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
    font-family: 'whatshelp' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.wh-icon-facebook-messenger:before {
    content: "\e900";
}
.wh-icon-whatshelp:before {
    content: "\e901";
}
.wh-icon-whatsapp:before {
    content: "\e902";
}
.wh-icon-telegram:before {
    content: "\e903";
}
```

Comment: Какой ответ возвращается от php? Что говорит по поводу JS консоль?

Comment: А как проверить?

Comment: JS консоль молчит

Comment: @Алкесандр-сухарь, открыли вашу страницу, открыли например в хроме консоль (F12) , потом открываете вкладку Network и заполняете вашу и форму и жмёте отправить. В нетворке видим запрос к файлу add_review.php кликаем по нему и видим там Headers, preview< response и вот смотрим что там в response возвращает

Comment: ну стоило у `ajax` проверять секцию `error`, а не только `success`.

Comment: this request has no response data available
Почему так?

Comment: response теперь возвращает смотрите правку

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button-send-review').click(function(){

   var name = $("#name_review").val();
   var good = $("#good_review").val();
   var bad = $("#bad_review").val();
   var comment = $("#comment_review").val();
   var iid = $("#button-send-review").attr("iid");

    if (name != "")
     {
          name_review = '1';
          $("#name_review").css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
      }else {
           name_review = '0';
           $("#name_review").css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
      }

    if (good != "")
       {
          good_review = '1';
          $("#good_review").css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
      }else {
          good_review = '0';
          $("#good_review").css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
      }

    if (bad != "")
     {
          bad_review = '1';
          $("#bad_review").css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
     }else {
          bad_review = '0';
          $("#bad_review").css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
     } 


            // Глобальная проверка и отправка отзыва

    if ( name_review == '1' && good_review == '1' && bad_review == '1')
      {
         $("#button-send-review").hide();
         $("#reload-img").show();

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/include/add_review.php",
         data: {
            id:iid,
            name:name,
            good:good,
            bad:bad,
            comment:comment
         },
         dataType: "json",
         cache: false,
         success: function() {
         setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
         }
         });  
         }         
});
```

Comment: не помогло,все тоже самое

Comment: Не помогло,но response теперь возвращает *смотрите правку*